# XCOPY copying files based on ID (With network paths)

Tags: batch-file

I have created a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which reads an ID from a CSV file and then searches for files with that ID contained within the title of log files created or modified within a specific date range to move them into a network folder.

At this moment, it seems the code is working (+-) but it is copying more files than it should, without looking at the ID.

It works on my local machine, so it seems the problem is regarding the network paths and it shows the UNC not supported path.

```
cd \\10.XX.ZZ.YY\ServersFiles
ECHO Will start reading the log files
for /f "usebackq tokens=4 delims=," %%a in ("\\10.XX.ZZ.YY\Folder1\Folder2\Execution_Logs\Tasks_Complete.csv") do (
    for /r %%i in (*%%a*.log) do xcopy /Y /D:%date_arg% "%%i" "\\10.XX.ZZ.YY\Logs\" 
)
```

[This is what I'm getting right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54657.jpg)

Comment: Please post the console result as text (copy it here and format it properly)! Do not post external links since they will become invalid at some point! Hint: take a look at [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If UNC paths aren't allowed, you could try using `PushD` instead of `CD`, which will create a temporary drive mapping to the network location. Throughout the rest of your script you could then use relative paths to the required locations.

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

REM Your %date_arg% variable should be defined somewhere around here.

PushD \\10.XX.ZZ.YY\ServersFiles 2>NUL || Exit /B
If Not Exist "..\Folder1\Folder2\Execution_Logs\Tasks_Complete.csv" Exit /B
Echo Will start reading the log files
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=4 Delims=," %%A In (
    "..\Folder1\Folder2\Execution_Logs\Tasks_Complete.csv")Do For /R %%B In (
    "*%%A*.log")Do XCopy "%%B" "..\Logs\" /D:%date_arg% /Y
PopD
EndLocal
Exit /B
```